# How to calculate the "AddAbsEquality" or "AddMultiplicationEqualit" using Google's CP-SAT solver for non-linear optimization?

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

My goal is to recover the data sequence based on a predicted sequence. Let us say the original sequence of data is **x_org = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]** but I receive the randomized data as **x_ran = [50, 40, 20, 10, 30]**. Now, my goal is to recover the pattern by keeping them the closest to the original pattern (minimizing recovery loss).

I used an almost similar approach as the "Assignment with Teams of Workers" and "Solving an Optimization Problem" available at google OR-tool's site [https://developers.google.com/optimization/assignment/assignment_teams] and [https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/integer_opt_cp].

I can minimize the sum of loss (error) but cannot calculate the square sum/absolute sum.

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

x_org = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
x_ran = [50, 40, 20, 10, 30]
n = len(x_org)


model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Defidning recovered data
x_rec = [model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, 'x_rec_%i') for i in range(n)]

# Defidning recovery loss        
x_loss = [model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, 'x_loss_%i' % i) for i in range(n)]

# Defining a (recovery) mapping matrix 
M = {}
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        M[i, j] = model.NewBoolVar('M[%i,%i]' % (i, j)) 
    
# -----------------Constraints---------------%
# Each sensor is assigned one unique measurement.
for i in range(n):
    model.Add(sum([M[i, j] for j in range(n)]) == 1)

# Each measurement is assigned one unique sensor.
for j in range(n):
    model.Add(sum([M[i, j] for i in range(n)]) == 1)


# Recovering the remapped data x_rec=M*x_ran (like, Ax =b)
for i in range(n):   
    model.Add(x_rec[i] == sum([M[i,j]*x_ran[j] for j in range(n)]))

# Loss = orginal data - recovered data
for i in range(n):
    x_loss[i] = x_org[i] - x_rec[i]

    
# minimizing recovery loss
model.Minimize(sum(x_loss))

#--------------- Calling solver -------------%

# Solves and prints out the solution.
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

print('Solve status: %s' % solver.StatusName(status))

if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    print('Optimal objective value: %i' % solver.ObjectiveValue())
    for i in range(n):
        print('x_loss[%i] = %i' %(i,solver.Value(x_loss[i])))
```

Then output without the absolute sum of error is:

```
Solve status: OPTIMAL
Optimal objective value: 0
x_loss[0] = -10
x_loss[1] = -30
x_loss[2] = 0
x_loss[3] = 30
x_loss[4] = 10
```

which shows even though the sum of loss is zero, the recovery is not correct. However, when I tried to add another int variable to store the absolute value of the loss [as shown below], the compiler gives an error.

```
# Defidning abs recovery loss        
x_loss_abs = [model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, 'x_loss_abs_%i' % i) for i in range(n)] 
# Loss = orginal data - recovered data
for i in range(n):
    model.AddAbsEquality(x_loss_abs[i], x_loss[i])
    #model.AddMultiplicationEquality(x_loss_abs[i], [x_loss[i], x_loss[i]])
```

The error is traceback is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-2a043a8fef8b> in <module>
      3 # Loss = orginal data - recovered data
      4 for i in range(n):
----> 5     model.AddAbsEquality(x_loss_abs[i], x_loss[i])

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.py in AddAbsEquality(self, target, var)
   1217         ct = Constraint(self.__model.constraints)
   1218         model_ct = self.__model.constraints[ct.Index()]
-> 1219         index = self.GetOrMakeIndex(var)
   1220         model_ct.int_max.vars.extend([index, -index - 1])
   1221         model_ct.int_max.target = self.GetOrMakeIndex(target)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.py in GetOrMakeIndex(self, arg)
   1397         else:
   1398             raise TypeError('NotSupported: model.GetOrMakeIndex(' + str(arg) +
-> 1399                             ')')
   1400 
   1401     def GetOrMakeBooleanIndex(self, arg):

TypeError: NotSupported: model.GetOrMakeIndex((-x_rec_%i + 10))
```

Could you please suggest how to minimize the absolute sum/square sum of the recovery loss? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that your original computation of `x_loss` needs to be absolute value.  The error amount you're trying to minimize should be unsigned.  `x_loss[i] = abs(x_org[i] - x_rec[i])`

Comment: Yes, that what I was trying to do but having an error in the implementation. Now, the comment by @hakank shows how to implement the absolute value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddAbsEquality` requires that the arguments are variables (not expressions such as `x_org[i] - x_rec[i]`. So one have to create a temporary decision variable before using it (here `v`). The following seems to work:

```
# ...
x_loss_abs = [model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, 'x_loss_abs_%i' % i) for i in range(n)]

# ...
for i in range(n):
   # x_loss[i] = x_org[i] - x_rec[i] # Original
   v = model.NewIntVar(-1000,1000,"v") # Temporary variable
   model.Add(v == x_org[i] - x_rec[i] )
   model.AddAbsEquality(x_loss_abs[i],v)

# ....
model.Minimize(sum(x_loss_abs))
```

The solution is then (I changed the output):

```
Optimal objective value: 0
x_org: [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]
x_rec: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
x_loss: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```